# How do I simulate a scroll wheel use on my Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop, touchpad, input-device, scroll-wheel

My laptop is a Windows 7 Lenovo 64-bit laptop with 2 GB RAM and it only has a touchpad. 
How do I simulate a scroll wheel?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable two finger vertical scrolling in the Touchpad settings in the Mouse Properties, and then scroll by dragging your two fingers vertically. [Learn more](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/HT062562)

Answer (score 0):

Older touchpads without multi-touch support have an option to scroll horizontally/vertically by swiping on the right/bottom edge of the touchpad. Just open the touchpad properties and see. For example the scrolling options in Synaptics can be seen in the following image

[image: Synaptics scrolling options]

As you can see it allows you to change the width of the sliding area as wll. There's also "Chiral Scrolling" where you move your finger in a circular motion to scroll. You can watch the demo video in the dialog to see how it works

Other touchpad drivers have similar feature:

- Cypress

  [image: Cypress driver]
- Dell

  [image: Dell driver]

Some touchpads also have a visual cue on the surface as well

[image: Visual touch scroll bar]

If the touchpad supports multi-touch then you can scroll with 2 fingers. Some old touchpads really support multi-touch but the feature is disabled in original drivers so you can only scroll with the edges. But you can update the driver to enable 2-finger scrolling